# how to authentify the user just for only once time?

Tags: android, authenticator

I have an application that needs authentication from a server.
I should use a class which **extended Authenticator Class** to set this lign of code every time I try to get a service from that server.

**Authenticator.setDefault(new UserAuthenticator("my_mail", "my_password"));**

and this is the UserAuthenticator class :

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

import android.util.Log;
public class UserAuthenticator extends Authenticator
{
    //counter used to iterate login process
    private int redirect;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    /**
     * UserAuthenticator constructor
     */
    public UserAuthenticator(String mail, String pwd)
    {
        this.email = mail;
        this.password = pwd;
        Log.d("email+password", email+password);
    }

    /**
     * <p>Called when password authorization is needed</p>
     *
     */
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
    {

        //to catch login redirect exception
        if(redirect>0){

            return null;
        }else{
            redirect ++;
        }

        /**
         * <p>Return the information (a data holder that is used by
         * Authenticator</p
         */ 
        return new PasswordAuthentication(email,
                password.toCharArray());
    }
    public PasswordAuthentication authenticationResult()
    {
        return getPasswordAuthentication();
    }

}
```

Is there any way to instantiate this class **just one time** to be used then (the user stay authenticated) in all the rest of activities.

I mean I want to authentify the user one time and do not repeat the instantiation of that class every time I need to request the server.

ps: I tried to make it a static inner class but it doesn’t work without instantiate it every time.
Maybe there is an other way in Android rather then Authenticator class because I knew this class in java web applications.

Comment: I never did it on Android itself but it sould be same so i try to suggest it. Cant you save the login state somewhere in one of the storage options? Like SQLite database and all that. And in the following app hierarchy you check for that state? Should be able like that. See here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: yes it's a good way but my client asks me to not store the password/mail user in any place in the application !!
I need to find a way to use this bit of code just one time in all the application and stay valid:
`Authenticator.setDefault(new UserAuthenticator("my_mail", "my_password"));`

I'm thinking about services,could be a good solution?

Comment: Why do you want to use `Authenticator`? You can have the exact functionality you're talking about by simply using `SharedPreferences`.